# Importing fortran subroutine within python MPI

Tags: python, fortran, mpi, f2py

I have a fortran subroutine and I want to import it inside a python MPI program? When I import the library in a serial python program i just use "import primes" where primes is a library compiled through "f2py -c primes.f90 -m primes" but when I import the same library inside a python MPI it shows the error " module not found". I want to specify that my fortran subroutine doesn't contain MPI calls.

My code :

```
    %%file sample.py
    from mpi4py import MPI
    import order
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    my_rank = comm.Get_rank()
    p = comm.Get_size()
    EM = order.calcenergy(config,coordinates,matrix,j1,j2,j3,j4)
    MPI.Finalize()
```

So the above code uses a fortran subroutine compiled through f2py which creates a library as "order" and can be imported in python. But when I compile this python MPI via " mpirun -n 2 python sample.py " it shows me an error "No module named order".

My question is : How to import a fortran routine within a python program which uses MPI?

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!
 do you have some working code that you could show?

Comment: thanks! however, code does not show correctly in comments. please [edit] your question to add in working code.

Comment: Do you have your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable properly propagated with `mpirun`?

Comment: Sorry I am new to parallel programming in python, I just installed mpi4py and it was working fine with simple programmes but I am unable to use my fortran subroutines with it.

Comment: It was a very dumb mistake on my side, I was compiling the MPI like !mpirun -n 6 python sample.py , it should be "python3 sample.py"